# Appending JSON like string in MySQL

Tags: mysql, dbmigrate

I have a JSON structured string stored in table "table", field "field", and need to modify this string directly for a database migration.

Let's say the string looks like `{"foo": false," bar": true}`, but can have an arbitrary length based off the number of key-value pairs in the string.

What I need to do is append this string on the fly, adding extra key-value pairs as needed.

My thoughts on how to do this would be perform something along the lines of:
`UPDATE table SET field = CONCAT(SUBSTR(field, 0, MAX(LENGTH(field))-1), ',"baz":false}`. The idea of this is to get a substring based on the max length - 1 of the string, and concat this with the new key-value pair.

SQL is not my strongest suit, so any help with this would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are looking for the [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) function